# Как получить query builder от модели?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть модел *Product*, Как получить query builder, для дальнейшего использования ?

Comment: DB::table('products') и дальше ваши запросы, если хотите работать с объектом используйте орм

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте статический метод query():

```
Product::query();
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_query